# How to pass an object from a view to a view that's embedded in a Navigationcontroller that's embedded in a Tabbar controller that's a container view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I want to pass an object from ViewA to ViewB, but ViewB is embedded in a Navigation controller that's embedded in a tab bar controller that's a view of a container view.

I've tried this in the prepareforsegue, but the value doesn't get passed to the destination.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"OpenProjectsSegue"]) {

        ContainerViewController *cvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        UITabBarController *tbc = cvc.tabBarController;
        UINavigationController *nav = tbc.viewControllers[0];
        IncomeViewController *vc = (IncomeViewController *)nav.topViewController;

        vc.projectIndexToOpen = @1;
        vc.testString = @"hola peru";
    } 
}
```

I have also tried `UITabBarController *tbc = cvc.childviewcontroller[0]`, but got an empty array error message.

Please help.  Thank you!

Comment: *prays* Lord, help my fellow brother overcome the troubles faced with this tragic setup. *finished prayer*

Comment: cvc.childviewcontroller[0] should have worked if your structure is as you say it is. Can you post an image of your storyboard somewhere?

Comment: this title makes me want to delete my account

Comment: here is a screenshot of my storyboard.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqd4s1t22vm26b1/Window%202014-04-21%20at%2011.06.45.png
Thanks =)

Comment: Hmm... looks like it should have worked. If you log cvc, does it give you the correct controller?

Comment: Sounds like a singleton or store it in the app delegate (ok, that's really a singleton approach as well)

Comment: @rdelmar I tried log the count of the child views which returned a 0, should be 2.

Comment: But have you logged cvc? Is it actually a ContainerViewController?

Comment: @rdelmar how do I logged cvc?  I don't follow =$

Comment: The same way you log any object, NSLog(@"%@",cvc). Also, which segue is "OpenProjectsSegue" in you image?

Comment: OpenProjectsSegue is the segue from OpenProjectTableView to ContainerView.  I get this when I log cvc.

<ContainerViewController: 0x109567230>

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that might work.

in ViewController.h at the top write:

```
extern UITabBarController *tbc;
```

then, in ViewController.m at the top write:

```
UITabBarController *tbc;
```

Also you must #include you class in whatever files you are trying to access the UITabBarController in, but this will make the UITabBarController a global variable and you could access it in multiple files.

Comment: Just tried that, it's still giving me the same error.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
=(

Comment: Looks like your problem is with the array.  You are reading from an empty array.  To debug this read everything from the array with a for loop (ex. for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)), right before                       UINavigationController *nav = tbc.viewControllers[0];

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of timing. The viewControllers property of the ContainerViewController is empty in prepareForSegue because all those other controllers haven't been initialized or added as children yet. I made the same setup as you have, and when I log various stages in their life cycle, this is what I get,

```
2014-04-21 17:01:23.930 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In ContainerViewController init
2014-04-21 17:01:23.931 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In prepareForSegue in ProjectTypeViewController
2014-04-21 17:01:23.931 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] ContainerViewController's children are (logged from prepareForSegue): (
)
2014-04-21 17:01:23.934 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In IncomeViewController init
2014-04-21 17:01:23.935 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In NavController init
2014-04-21 17:01:23.936 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In TabBarController init
2014-04-21 17:01:23.937 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In TabBarController viewDidLoad
2014-04-21 17:01:23.937 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In TabBarController didMoveToParentVC: <ContainerViewController: 0x8c227c0>
2014-04-21 17:01:23.937 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In ContainerViewController viewDidLoad
2014-04-21 17:01:23.940 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In NavController viewDidLoad
2014-04-21 17:01:23.948 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In IncomeViewController viewDidLoad
2014-04-21 17:01:24.452 PassingAheadInComplexHierarchyProblem[13653:60b] In IncomeViewController didMoveToParentVC: <NavController: 0x8e4f860>
```

As you can see, only the ContainerViewController has even been initialized at the time prepareForSegue is called.

One way to get the data you need in IncomeViewController, is to get a reference to ProjectTypeViewController, and query its properties. That reference is easy to get, because the ProjectTypeViewController will be the presentingViewController for IncomeViewController. So, if you had properties in both controllers called projectIndexToOpen, you could do this in IncomeViewController,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.projectIndexToOpen = [(ProjectTypeViewController *)self.presentingViewController projectIndexToOpen];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.projectIndexToOpen);
}
```

Comment: I tried that in IncomeViewController, but I get this error.  I'm thinking you can't get a reference from ProjectTypeViewController to IncomeViewController because it's embedded in a navigationcontroller and tabbarcontroller?

 -[UINavigationController projectIndexToOpen]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109585b20
2014-04-21 21:08:21.151 StartUpCalculator[886:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController projectIndexToOpen]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109585b20'

Comment: @gt3240, my sample app had the same structure as yours (with the navigation controller and tab bar controller), and it worked ok. Is the segue from ProjectTypeViewController to the container controller a modal one?

Comment: Yes, the segue is modal type.  Do you have anything in the prepareforsegue in ProjectTypeViewController?

Comment: @gt3240, no, not other than log statements. I don't know why presentingViewController would return the navigation controller. Is your code in viewDidLoad exactly the same as mine?

Comment: I have the same code in  viewDidLoad.  I think I'll just remove the containerview.  Thanks for the help.